# Find the index of an item in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a list of lists:

```
colours = [["#660000","#863030","#ba4a4a","#de7e7e","#ffaaaa"],["#a34b00","#d46200","#ff7a04","#ff9b42","#fec28d"],["#dfd248","#fff224","#eefd5d","#f5ff92","#f9ffbf"],["#006600","#308630","#4aba4a","#7ede7e","#aaffaa"]]
```

What's the cleanest way of searching the list and returning the position of one of the items, e.g. `"#660000"`?

I have looked at the `index` method, but that doesn't seem to unpack the list inside the list.

```
postion = colours.index("#660000")
```

gives: `ValueError: ['#660000'] is not in list`, not `[0][0]` as I expect...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
[(i, colour.index(c))
 for i, colour in enumerate(colours)
 if c in colour]
```

This will return a list of tuples where the first index is the position in the first list and second index the position in the second list (note: `c` is the colour you're looking for, that is, `"#660000"`).

For the example in the question, the returned value is:

```
[(0, 0)]
```

If you just need to find the first position in which the colour is found in a lazy way you can use this:

```
next(((i, colour.index(c))
      for i, colour in enumerate(colours)
      if c in colour),
     None)
```

This will return the tuple for the first element found or `None` if no element is found (you can also remove the `None` argument above in it will raise a `StopIteration` exception if no element is found).

Edit: As @RikPoggi correctly points out, if the number of matches is high, this will introduce some overhead because `colour` is iterated twice to find `c`. I assumed this to be reasonable for a low number of matches and to have an answer into a single expression. However, to avoid this, you can also define a method using the same idea as follows:

```
def find(c):
    for i, colour in enumerate(colours):
        try:
            j = colour.index(c)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        yield i, j

matches = [match for match in find('#660000')]
```

Note that since `find` is a generator you can actually use it as in the example above with `next` to stop at the first match and skip looking further.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you - is there a simple way to reference each of the items in the resulting tuple individually??

Comment: @JayGattuso You can access each item in the tuple using index notation. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I think so if item="your example" the item type is a list - [(0,0)], item[0] is a tuple - (0,0), I'm not sure how I can get to each '0' in a referencable way so I can plug the location back into a reciprocal array, so I can do e.g.  colours2[item] = 'foo'

Comment: I'm a dunce. I got it - apols for wasting your time. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't really like the idea of checking `if c in colour` and then calling `colour.index(c)`, seems a bit like a waste to me.

Comment: @RikPoggi If you don't do that, then you get a `ValueError: list.index(x): x not in list` exception from Python.

Comment: @burhan: I sure know that, but it doesn't make me like this approach.

Comment: @RikPoggi I suppose the alternative would be to try/except and then ignore the exception.

Comment: @burhan: Yes, that would be better. Or you could just forget about `index` and start looking for alternatives.

Comment: @RikPoggi Thanks for your comment. I agree on that more work than required is done and that this might be important if the number of matches is high. I updated my answer with some code slighty more complex for the cases in which a single expression doesn't do a good job.

Answer (score 9):

Using [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#enumerate) you could write a function like this one:

```
def find(target):
    for i,lst in enumerate(colours):
        for j,color in enumerate(lst):
            if color == "#660000":
                return (i, j)
    return (None, None)
```

Answer (score 9):

It would be perhaps more simple using [`numpy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where):

```
>>> import numpy
>>> ar = numpy.array(colours)
>>> numpy.where(ar=="#fff224")
(array([2]), array([1]))
```

As you see you'll get a tuple with all the row and column indexes.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to evade from iterating the target sublist twice, it seems that the best (and the most Pythonic) way to go is a loop:

```
def find_in_sublists(lst, value):
    for sub_i, sublist in enumerate(lst):
        try:
            return (sub_i, sublist.index(value))
        except ValueError:
            pass

    raise ValueError('%s is not in lists' % value)
```

Comment: *(1)* the `raise` statement is wrong indented, should be outside the for loop. *(2)* I don't like  the idea of raise a `ValueError`, a simple `(None, None)` or `(-1, -1)` would probably be a better design.

Comment: (1) fixed, thanks, (2) I just wanted it to be consistent with the list.index, but sure a tuple may be better.

Comment: Well, you may want the function to behave either like `list.index()` (which raises) or like `str.find()` (which does not). Without more details given, that's a completely arbitrary choice, the user will have to check the docs in any case.

Comment: Being consistent with `list.index` is exactly what I don't like. I don't see the point for that. When you call for example str.find() or use the in comparison you don't get the raising of a ValueError. The internal implelemtation of find_in_sublists() is unknown to the user, he doesn't care if you use index or whatever inside. *(I'm sorry I've messed up the flow the of the comments)* Anyway, yes, I agree that after a certain point is a matter of design taste.

Comment: There is no reason of choosing `str.find` contract over `list.index` either, no matter how the function is implemented. But on the other hand, your solution of iterating through the nested sequences seems to me better now in sense that it will work for any sequences, while my implementation is intended for lists only.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3, I used this pattern:

```
CATEGORIES = [   
    [1, 'New', 'Sub-Issue', '', 1],
    [2, 'Replace', 'Sub-Issue', '', 5],
    [3, 'Move', 'Sub-Issue', '', 7],
]

# return single item by indexing the sub list
next(c for c in CATEGORIES if c[0] == 2)
```

Comment: this will only work if the search key is in the first element of each sub-list; it's not 100% clear from the question but I think it's assumed that it could be anywhere. put another way: this will work to find `#660000` but not `#863030`

Answer (score -2):

another thing you can do is selecting the section of the list you want and then use index to find it

```
list_name[0].index("I want coffee")
```

Comment: but how do you know which "section of the list" you want? i.e. where do you get the value for `0` in your example without knowing the list structure ahead of time?