# serching for nested item in nested list [python]

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

this is my nested list

```
list = [[01,"ny",100], [02,'jr",200], [03, "la", 300,"ny"]]
```

My Question is:

how to search for an item in the a specific position of nested list
ex: i want to search for the item "ny" in the 2nd position of nested list
means, my search has to match the item "ny" in only [][1] position it has to ignore "ny" in [3][3].

Comment: Possible duplicate with a few nice options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553638/python-find-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list-of-lists

Comment: Do you only care about knowing if there is one or do you need the position(s?) of matching values?

Comment: That list doesn't have a position `[3][3]`.  The highest it goes is `[2][3]`.

Comment: Please fix your question. There are at least three typos... (quotes in code part and list numbers in last sentence)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

```
>>> lst  = [[01,"ny",100], [02,"jr",200], [03, "la", 300,"ny"]]
>>> [sublst for sublst in lst if sublst[1] == "ny"]
[[1, 'ny', 100]]
```

To check whether `ny` exists, use [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) with generator expression:

```
>>> any(sublist[1] == "ny" for sublist in lst)
True
>>> any(sublist[1] == "xy" for sublist in lst)
False
```

BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name. It shadows builtin function [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list).

**UPDATE**: You can also use following as suggested by @DSM.

```
>>> "ny" in (sublist[1] for sublist in lst)
True
```

Comment: I'd simply write `"ny" in (sublst[1] for sublst in lst)`.  Or at least `any(sublst[1] == "ny" for sublst in lst)`.

Comment: @DSM, Thank you for suggestion. I added that and updated the answer to use `any(sublist[1] == "ny" for sublist in lst)`. It's nice.

Answer (score 0):

first, don't overwrite the `list` built-in.

second, you can use the `filter` built-in, to find all the matches:

```
list_ = [[01,"ny",100], [02,"jr",200], [03, "la", 300,"ny"]]
matches = filter(lambda element: element[1] == 'ny', list_)
```

Comment: thanks for help, it's working, How to retrieve boolean value,
if item exist in that position then return true, else false

Answer (score -1):

exactly how you would think

```
list[0][1]
```

EDIT:

```
for inner in list:
    if inner[1] == 'ny':
        ...
```

Comment: but how to search for that item in program?

Comment: i want to search in only 2nd position of nested list(just like these list[][1]