# Is there a way to find if an item in a nested list exists?

Tags: python, nested-lists

I was wondering if there was a way to do something like this is Python. Any ideas?

```
inches = ["inches", "inch", "in"]
centimeters = ["centimeters", "centimeter", "cm"]
allUnits = [inches, centimeters]
unit = input("Enter unit here... ")
if unit not in allUnits:
    print("Invalid unit!")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [serching for nested item in nested list \[python\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968014/serching-for-nested-item-in-nested-list-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close:

```
inches = ["inches", "inch", "in"]
centimeters = ["centimeters", "centimeter", "cm"]
allUnits = [*inches, *centimeters] # notice the `*`
unit = input("Enter unit here... ")
if unit.lower() not in allUnits:
    print("Invalid unit!")
```

Should do the trick.

The `*` operator unwinds the lists into their constituent elements. Which can then be used to create a new list. So you can flatten the two lists into one that way.

I also added `unit.lower()` to make the string comparison case-independent.

Comment: This is arguably better than list concatenation since it should be better for larger lists

Answer (score 1):

Just add lists:

```py
inches = ["inches", "inch", "in"]
centimeters = ["centimeters", "centimeter", "cm"]
allUnits = inches + centimeters
unit = input("Enter unit here... ")
if unit not in allUnits:
    print("Invalid unit!")
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
if unit not in inches + centimeters:
    print("Invalid unit!")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use array of arrays you can do like that. Inspired by C++.

```
def isInArray(array, unit):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        for j in array[i]:
            if j == unit:
                return True;
    return False

unit = input("Enter unit here... ")
if not isInArray(allUnits, unit):
    print("Invalid unit!")
```