# Swap two numbers in list of tuples (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a complete matching in the form:

```
M=[(1,3),(2,4),(5,6)]
```

I want to perform a simple transposition on it.

Function `si(M)` should swap the positions of numbers `i` and `i+1`.

For instance `s2(M)` should swap the positions of numbers `2` and `3`:

`s2(M)` should return:

```
[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
```

Preferably written in python3 code.

Comment: SO is not a place to ask random people to do your work for you.. please try to code it yourself and if you encounter any problems ask about them.

Comment: That's very good. So, write some code, and if you run into problems, write an on-topic question and post it here.

Comment: Please post your own attempt at writing this function & we'll help you fix it. Tuples aren't really suitable for this since they're immutable. Your transpose function should take two arguments: the list you want to transpose, and the index.

Comment: @Alex Gain One method is to first convert **list of tuples** to **list of lists** then swap the values you want by using index of the elements in the list of lists; generally let us assume your list of list is L. You can use L[i][j] for the index of elements and swapping where **i** will vary from 0 to length of your list and **j** will vary from 0 to 1.

Comment: This is an extremely small part of what I'm working on and is quite similar in nature to a lot of other questions involving functions on data structures.

Thank you for the feedback, though.

Comment: Thank you for the pseudocode, very much appreciated. @TanmayaMeher

Comment: @AlexGain You will get some idea here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14831830/convert-a-list-of-tuples-to-a-list-of-lists and for finding index of numbers in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553638/python-find-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list-of-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone curious, I quickly wrote a function for it. First off, the complete matching is written as a 2D list.

The following function is needed before writing the main one:

```
def index_2d(myList, v): #Returns tuple containing the position of v in the 2D list
  for i, x in enumerate(myList):
     if v in x:
        return (i, x.index(v))
```

eg. If the complete matching is M=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]], index_2d(M, 4) would return (1,1).

Next, the simple transposition function:

```
def s(M,n):
   a=index_2d(M,n)
   b=index_2d(M,n+1)
   M[a[0]][a[1]], M[b[0]][b[1]] = M[b[0]][b[1]], M[a[0]][a[1]]
   return M
```

I wasn't concerned with efficiency, so perhaps there is more efficient code than this.