# Finding the index of an element in nested lists in python

Tags: python, nested-lists

I am trying to get the index of an element in nested lists in python - for example `[[a, b, c], [d, e, f], [g,h]]` (not all lists are the same size).
I have tried using

```
strand_value= [x[0] for x in np.where(min_value_of_non_empty_strands=="a")]
```

but this is only returning an empty list, even though the element is present. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: In this instance, 0, I would then try using x[1] to get 0 again - I want to know which list it's in and which position within the list

Comment: should it not be 0 0 since you are looking for `a`

Comment: I am trying to find the index of any given string, for which I do not know its position or which list it is in - if I can get 0 0 straight away, I would find that very helpful

Comment: If you have a list of strings, then it is much easier to solve than a list of lists of stings.

Comment: Why the `numpy` tag?  Your expression using `np.where` does not make sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the index of an item in a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553638/find-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
def find_in_list_of_list(mylist, char):
    for sub_list in mylist:
        if char in sub_list:
            return (mylist.index(sub_list), sub_list.index(char))
    raise ValueError("'{char}' is not in list".format(char = char))

example_list = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']]

find_in_list_of_list(example_list, 'b')
(0, 1)
```

Comment: This is O(N^2) and will be slow if `mylist` is long.

Comment: A more general solution would be better for a problem like this. Check out My answer.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this using List comprehension and enumerate

**Code:**

```
lst=[["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g","h"]]
check="a"
print ["{} {}".format(index1,index2) for index1,value1 in enumerate(lst) for index2,value2 in enumerate(value1) if value2==check]
```

**Output:**

```
['0 0']
```

**Steps:**

- I have enumerated through the List of List and got it's index and list
- Then I have  enumerated  over the gotten list and checked if it matches the `check` variable and written it to list if so

This gives all possible output

**i.e.)**

**Code2:**

```
lst=[["a", "b", "c","a"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g","h"]]
check="a"
print ["{} {}".format(index1,index2) for index1,value1 in enumerate(lst) for index2,value2 in enumerate(value1) if value2==check]
```

**Gives:**

```
['0 0', '0 3']
```

**Notes:**

- You can easily turn this into list of list instead of string if you want

Answer (score 2):

suppose your list is like this:

```
lst = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g','h']]
list_no = 0
pos = 0
for x in range(0,len(lst)):
    try:
        pos = lst[x].index('e')
        break
    except:
        pass

list_no = x
```

`list_no` gives the list number and `pos` gives the position in that list

Answer (score 0):

does this suffice?

```
array = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']]
for subarray in array:
    if 'a' in subarray:
        print(array.index(subarray), '-', subarray.index('a'))
```

This will return 0 - 0. First zero is the index of the subarray inside array, and the last zero is the 'a' index inside subarray.

Answer (score 0):

Reworked Bhrigu Srivastava's proposal:

```
def findinlst(lst, val):
    for x in range(0, len(lst)):
        try:
            pos = lst[x].index(val)
            return [x, pos]
        except:
            continue
    return [False, False]  # whatever one wants to get if value not found

arr = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h']]

findinlst(arr, 'b')
[0, 1]

findInLst(arr, 'g')
[2, 0]

findinlst(arr, 'w')
[False, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own `findIndex` function, this looks like Javascipt's `Array.prototype.findIndex`

```
def findIndex(callback, list):
    for index, element in enumerate(list):
        if callback(element):
            return index
    return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of "amateur" approach and yet very easy to understand:

Creating a flag boolean value that will execute the result based on if it is True or False with a nested for loop.

```
entry=input()
listtt=[["a","b","c"],["d","e","f"],["g","h"]]
found=False
for sublist in listtt:
    for charr in sublist:
        if entry==charr:
            print(f"'{entry}' found in sublist {listtt.index(sublist)} with index {sublist.index(charr)}")
            found=True
            break
if found==False:
    print(f"'{entry}' not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on DainDwarf's answer, this will return multiple values if the searched item is in more than one of the nested lists:

```
def find_in_list_of_list(mylist, char):
    found_list = []
    for sub_list in mylist:
        if char in sub_list:
            found_list.append(f'({mylist.index(sub_list)}, {sub_list.index(char)})')
    if len(found_list) > 0:
        return found_list


example_list = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]

print(find_in_list_of_list(example_list, 'c'))
```

I also got en error when changing the search from 'b' to 'x' in Dwarf's code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    print(find_in_list_of_list(example_list, 'x'))
  File "C:\main.py", line 5, in find_in_list_of_list
    raise ValueError("'{char}' is not in list".format(char = char))
ValueError: 'x' is not in list
```