# Finding an element in nested python list and then replacing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I have a nested list and I am trying to replace a certain element of the list with something else.

```
  NL = [[1,2,3],
       [4,5,6],
       [7,8,9]];
```

Now, I need to update the list, let's say the user wants to change element at NL[1][1] (i.e. 5) to 'X'.

NL will be updated as

```
  NL = [[1,2,3],
       [4,'X',6],
       [7,8,9]];`
```

I am having trouble trying to find the position of the element and then changing it. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the index of an element in nested lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938488/finding-the-index-of-an-element-in-nested-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `numpy`:

```
NL = np.array(NL)

mask = np.where(NL == 5)
NL[mask] = 10
```

---

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4, 10,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9]])
```

---

**Solution2:**

```
def get_index(num, List):
    for row, i in enumerate(List):
        if num in i:
            return row, i.index(num)
    return -1

idx = get_index(5,NL)
if idx>0:
    NL[idx[0]][idx[1]] = 7
```

---

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 7, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Fancy solution! But I feel like importing an entire library is a bit overkill for something you can do in four lines without the import...

Comment: Yeah but it's the most efficient solution. But for this task, a normal list method will do the job.

Comment: true, I guess it really depends on the length of their lists (and whether they use numpy anyway in other lines :) )

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 indexes, 1 for the what nested list you want and one for what element of the nested list you want.

So in this case you want the 2nd list's 2nd element:

```
NL[1][1]='X'
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 'X', 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you need to find the element `5` and want to replace it with `10`.
We iterate through the outer list and then each inner-list's elements. Once we find the element we look for, we can replace it by the indexes. We use enumerate to have the indexes once we find a matching element.

The following code replaces ALL matching elements (all occurences of `5`).

```
NL = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]

print(NL)  # prints: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

for i, sublist in enumerate(NL):
    for y, element in enumerate(sublist):
        if element == 5:
            NL[i][y] = 10

print(NL)  # prints: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 10, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will replace only the first occurrence of `item_to_replace`. If you want it to replace in all sublist then remove the `break` statement from `try` block.

```
item_to_replace = 5
for lst in NL:
    try:
        index = lst.index(item_to_replace)
        lst[index] = # your replacement for item_to_replace
        break
    except ValueError:
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

You should access to element by indexes. You have 2D list (array) so you should use 2 indexes: `NL[1][1] = "X"`.

**Complete code:**

```
NL = [[1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6],
      [7, 8, 9]]

print("Original: {}".format(NL))

NL[1][1] = "X"

print("New: {}".format(NL))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
Original: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
New: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 'X', 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Answer (score 0):

just use NL[1][1] = 'X'

then print(NL)

Answer (score 0):

> I am having trouble trying to find the position of the element and then changing it.

Most of the answers here seem to have missed that part, and assumed you *had* the position.

---

---

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
NL = [[1,2,3],
      [4,5,6],
      [7,8,9]]

NL = [['X' if i==5 else i for i in j] for j in NL]

print(NL)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [4,'X',6],
 [7, 8, 9]]
```