# Find a specific value in a large tree of sublists

Tags: python, list, sublist

I have some code that generates a list that looks something like this:

```
chrs = [[["a",["b","c"]],["d","e"],"f"],["g",[["h","i"],"j"]]]
```

Now I need to find a specific value in some kind of list like this.
I wrote some code to do this, but it seems to get stuck in an infinite loop:

```
def locate_value(v,chrs):                       #
    checked=[[]]                                # Set up the values
    index_list=[]                               #
    inside=0                                    #
    cur=[0,0]                                   #
                                                #
    while True:                                 #
        if chrs[cur[0]] == v:                   # If found, end the loop and return the index_list
            return index_list                   #
                                                #
        if type(chrs[cur[0]]) != list:          # If the current is not a list, skip this one
            checked[inside].append(cur[0])      #
            index_list = []                     #
                                                #
        else:                                   #
            try:                                #
                if cur[0] in gone[inside]:      # If the current has been done before, skip it
                    cur[0] += 1                 #
                                                #
                else:                           # And if not, move 1 space deeper
                    checked.append([])          #
                    index_list.append(cur[0])   #
                    cur[1] = cur[0]             #
                    cur[0] = 0                  #
                    inside += 1                 #
                                                #
            except IndexError:                  # And if a sublist is fully checked, block it too
                checked[inside].append(cur[1])  #



print(locate_value("e",[[["a",["b","c"]],["d","e"],"f"],["g",[["h","i"],"j"]]]))
```

> Editing me just realised how bad this code is

In this example, the function `locate_value` should return `[0, 1, 1]`, as `list[0][1][1]` is `"e"`

But when I run this, I get stuck in an infinite loop
Can anyone tell me what is wrong, and maybe give me some code that actually ***works*** for once.

The list is made with user input, so I have no idea how deep it is.
Though a python-3 only solution is fine, I would prefer one that supports python-2, too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the index of an element in nested lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33938488/finding-the-index-of-an-element-in-nested-lists-in-python)

Comment: @BhagyeshDudhediya Those seem to work only for lists of lists, not for arbitrary/irregular nesting.

Comment: "and maybe give me some code that actually works for once" Oh, I'm sorry, are you not satisfied with our free-of-charge coding support?

Comment: No, I mean MY code

Comment: Cuz mine never works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a recursion function:

```
def locate_value(v, chrs, idx=[]):
    for j, i in enumerate(chrs):
        if isinstance(i, list):
            yield from find(v, i, idx + [j])
        elif i == v:
            yield idx + [j]
```

Another version to keep your original signature function:

```
def locate_value(v, chrs):
    for j, i in enumerate(chrs):
        if isinstance(i, list):
            yield from ([j, *idx] for idx in locate_value(v, i))
        elif i == v:
            yield [j]
```

Output:

```
>>> list(locate_value('e', chrs, []))
[[0, 1, 1]]

# case of multiple 'e'
# chrs = [[["a",["b","c"]],["d","e"],"f"],["g",[["h","e"],"j"]]]

>>> list(locate_value('e', chrs))
[[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 1]]
```

*Greatly improved by @tobias_k*

Comment: You should change this to `yield from find(...)` and `yield idx + [j]` to make it much more useful, for finding just the `next` or all such index-tuples.

Comment: @tobias_k. Thanks for this improved code. I am really very grateful to you.

Comment: instead of passing [] as an argument, change `def locate_value(c, chrs, idx):` to `def locate_value(c, chrs, idx=[]):`. This will be more pythonic.

Comment: @GoAmeer030. Read https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/

Comment: Alternatively, `idx`-free version, using `yield from ([j, *idx] for idx in find(c, i))` and `yield [j]` respectively.

Comment: I updated my answer with the two solutions.

Comment: Worked! One thing I forgot to mention was that my list also had some tuples in it, but I just adjusted it to look for tuples to.

Answer (score 2):

The following will work:

```
def locate_value(v, chrs):
    if v == chrs:
        return []
    if not isinstance(chrs, list):
        raise IndexError
    for i, c in enumerate(chrs):
        try:
            return [i] + locate_value(v, c)
        except IndexError:
            pass
    raise IndexError


locate_value("e", [[["a",["b","c"]],["d","e"],"f"],["g",[["h","i"],"j"]]])
# [0, 1, 1]
```

Note that `str` objects are iterables themselves, so recursively keeping iterating their elements (strings yet again) will never end.

Comment: Good answer, but the other one was shorter.

Comment: It depends on your preferences. Some people prefer simple and readable answers compared to short answers that are difficult to understand.