# How can I get the index of a nested list item?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, indexing, nested

What would be an efficient and pythonic way to get the index of a nested list item?

For example:

```
some_list = [ [apple, pear, grape], [orange, plum], [kiwi, pineapple] ]
```

How can I grab the index of 'plum'?

Comment: you want `[1][1]` ?

Comment: Thanks. I looking at all you suggestions.  I need to get it as short and sweet as possible.

Comment: Please note I'm looking for the *index* not the value.

Comment: You should really say what exactly you want. And provide valid test data, not something with seven undefined variables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the index of an item in a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553638/find-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
[(i, el.index("plum")) for i, el in enumerate(some_list) if "plum" in el]
```

Output:

```
[(1, 1)]
```

Comment: I'm going to work with this answer, the list comp seems efficient.  Thanks all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Simple iteration through the indices of a nested list (only for the case of two levels, though).

```
def findelm(element, list):
    x = 0 
    while x < len(list):
        y = 0
        while y < len(list[x]):
            if list[x][y] == element: print "({},{})".format(x,y)
            y = y + 1
        x = x + 1
```

Notably this fails for the case of a list element not being a list itself.

I.e.:

Input (fail case-- selected element not list):

```
list = ["hey", "ho", ["hi", "haha", "help"], "hooha"]
findelm("hey", list)
```

Output (fail case-- selected element not list):

```
# Nothing!
```

VS

Input (lucky case-- selected element a list):

```
list = ["hey", "ho", ["hi", "haha", "help"], "hooha"]
findelm("haha", list)
```

Output (lucky case-- selected element a list):

```
(2,1)
```

VS

Input (appropriate use case):

```
list = [["hey"], ["ho"], ["hi", "haha", "help"], ["hooha"]]
findelm("hey", list)
```

Output (appropriate use case):

```
(0,0)
```

Comment: Thanks for contribution to SO. Please take time and visit [SO Answering Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering). You should explain why you think this is a right answer

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate your list `some_list`, I turned its sub-elements into string so as to handle them. Thus, if one has

```
>>> some_list = [
        ['apple', 'pear', 'grape'], 
        ['orange', 'plum'],
        ['kiwi', 'pineapple']
    ]
```

And one wants to find the index and the sub-index of the string element `'plum'`

```
>>> to_find = 'plum'
```

Then

```
>>> [(index_,sub_list.index(to_find))\
     for index_, sub_list in enumerate(some_list)\
     if to_find in sub_list]
[(1, 1)]
```

would get indexes you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Setup**

```
a = [ ['apple', 'pear', 'grape'], ['orange', 'plum'], ['kiwi', 'pineapple'] ]
Out[57]: [['apple', 'pear', 'grape'], ['orange', 'plum'], ['kiwi', 'pineapple']]
```

**Solution**

```
#Iterate the list of lists and build a list of dicts and then merge the dicts into one dict with words as keys and their index as values.

dict(sum([{j:[k,i] for i,j in enumerate(v)}.items() for k,v in enumerate(a)],[])).get('plum')
Out[58]: [1, 1]

dict(sum([{j:[k,i] for i,j in enumerate(v)}.items() for k,v in enumerate(a)],[])).get('apple')
Out[59]: [0, 0]
```

Answer (score -1):

here are some examples:

```
apple = some_list[0][0]
plum = some_list[1][1]
kiwi = some_list[2][0]
```