# Python enumerate list to str

Tags: python-2.7, list

How do I do a quick search for element in the list of lists, looking for getting **True** in the output of last command below. *Also is there a quick way to get the index ('0' and '2' in the example) instead of looping thru the list?*

```
l=[['10.98.78.235', '1'], ['10.98.78.236', '2'], ['10.98.78.235', '10']]
>>> ['10.198.78.235', '1'] in l
True
>>> '10.198.78.235' in l
False
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - find the index of an item in a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9553638/python-find-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list-of-lists)

Comment: What are you using the structure for? It looks like you may be better of using a dict (or converting to a dict).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine `list comprehension` with index syntax and `enumerate`

```
l=[['10.98.78.235', '1'], ['10.98.78.236', '2'], ['10.98.78.235', '1']]

search=['10.98.78.235', '1']
indexes=[index for index,item in enumerate(l) if search in [item] ] ]

print indexes
```

will produce :

```
[0, 2]
```

or :

```
l=[['10.98.78.235', '1'], ['10.98.78.236', '2'], ['10.98.78.235', '10']]

search='10.98.78.235'
indexes=[index for index,item in enumerate(l) if search in item ]

print indexes
```

will produce :

```
[0, 2]
```

https://repl.it/MuGF

Comment: I search for '10.98.78.235', not for ['10.98.78.235', '1']

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

l=np.array([['10.98.78.235', '1'], ['10.98.78.236', '2'], ['10.98.78.235', '10']])
matches = np.where((l == '10.98.78.235'))
positions = np.transpose(matches)
print positions
```

Giving as a result the list of the matches on every dimension of the list (i.e. first list for rows, second list for columns):

```
[[0 0]
 [2 0]]
```

If you just want to get the rows, there is no need to use `transpose`:

```
rows = matches[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want this:

```
search = ['10.98.78.235', '1']
result = [i for i, item in enumerate(l) if item[0] == search[0] and search[1] in item[1]]
```